# SQL Server LEN function reports wrong result

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

Let's say we have the following casting of an int number into binary value i.e 
`cast(120 as binary(8))` or any other int number into `binary(8)`.

What we normally expect from `len(cast(120 as binary(8))) = 8` and this is true unless we try with number 32 where `select len(cast(32 as binary(8)))` returns 7 !

Is this a bug of SQL Server?

Answer (score 4):

Not a bug, it's how [LEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) works. LEN:

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression,
>   **excluding trailing spaces.**

The definition of "trailing space" seems to differ based the datatype. For binary values, a trailing space is when the binary *representation* "20". In the BOL entry for LEN there is a note that reads,

> Use the LEN to return the number of characters encoded into a given
>   string expression, and DATALENGTH to return the size in bytes for a
>   given string expression. **These outputs may differ depending on the**
>   **data type and type of encoding used in the [value]**. For more
>   information on storage differences between different encoding types,
>   see Collation and Unicode Support.

With Binary the length (`LEN`) is reduced by 1 for binary values that end with 20, by 2 for values that end with 2020, etc. Again, it's treating that value like a trailing space. `DATALENGTH` resolves this. Note this SQL:

```
DECLARE 
  @string VARCHAR(100) = '1234567 ',
  @binary BINARY(8)    = 32;

SELECT [Type] = 'string',   [Len] = LEN(@string), [Datalength] = DATALENGTH(@string)
UNION ALL
SELECT [Type] = 'binary(8)', [Len] = LEN(@binary), [Datalength] = DATALENGTH(@binary);
```

**Returns:**

```
Type      Len         Datalength
--------- ----------- -----------
string    7           8
binary(8) 7           8
```

Using my rangeAB function ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819150/convert-all-xml-special-characters-back-to-regular-characters-within-sql)) I created this query:

```
SELECT 
  N            = r.RN,
  Binaryvalue  = CAST(r.RN AS binary(8)), 
  [Len]        = LEN(CAST(r.RN AS binary(8))),
  [DataLength] = DATALENGTH(CAST(r.RN AS binary(8)))
FROM     dbo.rangeAB(0,10000,1,0) AS r
WHERE    LEN(CAST(r.RN AS binary(8))) <> 8
ORDER BY N;
```

Note these results:

```
N                    Binaryvalue        Len         DataLength
-------------------- ------------------ ----------- -----------
32                   0x0000000000000020 7           8
288                  0x0000000000000120 7           8
544                  0x0000000000000220 7           8
800                  0x0000000000000320 7           8
1056                 0x0000000000000420 7           8
1312                 0x0000000000000520 7           8
1568                 0x0000000000000620 7           8
1824                 0x0000000000000720 7           8
2080                 0x0000000000000820 7           8
2336                 0x0000000000000920 7           8
2592                 0x0000000000000A20 7           8
2848                 0x0000000000000B20 7           8
3104                 0x0000000000000C20 7           8
3360                 0x0000000000000D20 7           8
3616                 0x0000000000000E20 7           8
3872                 0x0000000000000F20 7           8
4128                 0x0000000000001020 7           8
4384                 0x0000000000001120 7           8
4640                 0x0000000000001220 7           8
4896                 0x0000000000001320 7           8
5152                 0x0000000000001420 7           8
5408                 0x0000000000001520 7           8
5664                 0x0000000000001620 7           8
5920                 0x0000000000001720 7           8
6176                 0x0000000000001820 7           8
6432                 0x0000000000001920 7           8
6688                 0x0000000000001A20 7           8
6944                 0x0000000000001B20 7           8
7200                 0x0000000000001C20 7           8
7456                 0x0000000000001D20 7           8
7712                 0x0000000000001E20 7           8
7968                 0x0000000000001F20 7           8
8224                 0x0000000000002020 6           8
8480                 0x0000000000002120 7           8
8736                 0x0000000000002220 7           8
8992                 0x0000000000002320 7           8
9248                 0x0000000000002420 7           8
9504                 0x0000000000002520 7           8
9760                 0x0000000000002620 7           8
```

Note how the `LEN` of `CAST(8224 AS binary(8)` is 6; because 8224 ends with 2020 which is treated like two spaces:

```
8224                 0x0000000000002020 6           8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alan for your answer. Although I was aware of dataLength function I didn't think (and knew) the nature of Len function for binary data. I have already replaced it in my code by DataLenght.